# In-place switching between swing components

Tags: swing, jtable, jtree

In my swing application, I would like to display the same date using JTree and JTable.
Components should be displayed/shown interchangeably, depending on user choice (for example with toggle button). If button is pressed then JTree should be shown, if not then JTable.
The Question: How to do it in proper way.
I have tried stacklayout, displaying next/previous component, but it does not seem to be good solution. Both component takes memory, both exists simultaneously.
Second solution, in may opinion, is to remove component from panel, and create new one. It can be also memory/time consuming. 
Do you have any propositions or solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) seems to be the best fit for this, but it will of course also keep both components in memory. Do you actually have any indication that this is a problem, or are you just suffering from premature optimization worries?

Comment: I did not try CardLayout yet, so it is more like my concerns about performance. Currently we suffer from OutOfMemory Exception when loading huge amount of data in table (I know we should think about lazy-loading, but it's not a subject). But anyway, thank for opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Removing existing components and adding new components to a panel should not be that much of a problem performance-wise. And if you make sure that there is no references to the removed objects (your `JTree` for example), you should not have any memory problems.